# Drawing over magnifier window (Magnification API)

Tags: c++, winapi, magnification-api

I′m creating an app by using windows magnification API and need to draw over there, but have no idea HOW.
I was try to draw on DC, but it not work.

Comment: Draw over what exactly? Draw on top of the magnifier itself? Why?

Comment: @RemyLebeau i want to draw pixel grid. I was try put child window and drawing on there, but it blink. http://gyazo.com/4e458509d62f8847c2d2accc558c5357.png?1348547837

Answer (score 0):

You can't if your application doesn't have uiAccess=true in its manifest and runned from folder different from Program Files.